# Dialog name for the Ctrl-f6 in eclipse

Tags: java, user-interface, eclipse-plugin

What is the name of this dialog? I cannot use plugin spy as this dialog does not stay open very long. This is the dialog to switch editor.

Comment: I assume you would like to know the name of the class that implements this dialog. I that's the case, you might want to rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+F6 — Switch between last used files.

It shows you the list of last used files. If you hold Ctrl and press F6 more than once - you will iterate on this list.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the word 'dialog' might be misleading.  This 'popup list' interface doesn't have window decorations, so it's hard to say whether it's a dialog, frame or something else.  This might mean you're looking in the wrong places.

FYI, Switch Editor (CTRL+F6), Switch View (CTRL+F7) and Switch Perspective (CTRL+F8) all use the same type of popup so finding one of their class names should help you find what you're looking for.

This [SWT spy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968770/is-there-a-swt-debugger-spy) might help you find the component.  To get around the issue with it not being open long, press and release the SHIFT key while the list is open, and it will now stay open if you release all the keys, and will only close if you click away or use ESC/ENTER.